# Unity 3D. How to find out where the movement of an object is directed relative to its rotation?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to make a 3d top down character controller and animate it.
To begin with, I made a code for the character's movement relative to the camera. And this code works, the character walks and turns well.

```
Vector3 inputDirection = new Vector3(_input.GetAxis.x, 0, _input.GetAxis.y);

float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + _camera.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transformPlayer.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref _turnVelocity, TurnSmoothTime);

transformPlayer.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

Vector3 moveDirection = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
moveDirectionNormalized = moveDirection.normalized;

_characterPlayer.Move(moveDirectionNormalized * SpeedMultiplier * Time.deltaTime);
```

The character model is a child object of `_characterPlayer`.
And if, when the character moves, an enemy gets into his radius, then the player's model will turn towards the enemy, and the character himself will go further along the `moveDirectionNormalized`.
For turns, I wrote the following code:

```
if (NearestEnemyAtAttackRadius != null)
{
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(NearestEnemyAtAttackRadius.transform.position - MeshCharacter.position);

    MeshCharacter.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(MeshCharacter.rotation, rotation, 800f * Time.deltaTime);
}
else
{
    MeshCharacter.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(MeshCharacter.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero), 800f * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Now if there is an enemy nearby, my character swings towards the enemy, and if there is no enemy or the enemy has left the radius, then the initial state is returned.
And here my problem begins. I wanted to add an animation of the movement. The character has 4 animations: movement with a tilt to the right, left, forward and backward.
In the `Animator`, I made a Blend Tree (2d simple direction) with 4 animations. Added 2 Float values `MoveDirectionX`, `MoveDirectionY` correctly configured for all motion pos x and pos y.
And if I am in MoveDirectionX, MoveDirectionY will feed the vector `moveDirectionNormalized`, then it does not work correctly. The values of `moveDirectionNormalized` do not depend on the repetition of my model in any way, and if my character moves away from the enemy, he looks at the enemy but in fact goes backwards, the animation should turn on as he leans back. But now `moveDirectionNormalized` does not depend on the repetition of my model, and the character tilt animations randomly switch depending on `moveDirectionNormalized`. As I understand it, it is necessary to create a new vector that will take into account the rotation of my model, but I do not understand how to do this.

As a result, I want to get a vector where x - shows where the character is moving to the left or right (from -1 to 1) and y - shows the movement forward, backward (also from -1 to 1), and this vector should take into account the rotation of the player.  At the moment, in the character model, only y changes in rotation.  moveDirectionNormalized returns a value that indicates where the movement is directed relative to world space.  And I need to make a vector that will return directions relative to the player's rotation.  That is, if the character's gaze is directed at the enemy, and the character himself retreats from him, I would like to receive a vector (0, -1).  And if the player's gaze is directed at the enemy and he goes to the right (I remind you that the player is constantly looking towards the enemy, that is, you can walk around the enemy and the character will constantly turn in his direction), then I would like to get a vector (1,0)

Comment: If you were using physics the velocity would tell you.  But as you teleport. You dont move. You teleport. You could remember last pos each time you move.

Comment: Didn't understand you a bit.  I am using the standard unity character controller for movement.  The movement itself works well, I want to get some more information about this movement, which I will use in the animators.  I need to get a vector where x - indicates whether the character is moving left or right (from -1 to 1) and y - indicates movement forward, backward (also from -1 to 1), and this vector should take into account the player's rotation.  At the moment, in the character model, only y changes in rotation.

Comment: At the moment, in the character model, only y changes in rotation.  moveDirectionNormalized returns a value that indicates where the movement is directed relative to world space.  And I need to make a vector that will return directions relative to the player's rotation.  That is, if the character's gaze is directed at the enemy, and the character himself retreats from him, I would like to receive a vector (0, -1).

Comment: And if the player's gaze is directed at the enemy and he goes to the right (I remind you that the player is constantly looking towards the enemy, that is, you can walk around the enemy and the character will constantly turn in his direction), then I would like to get a vector (1,0)

Comment: For all the text on this page, I still don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand, but if I do, this should help:
You can use `Quaternion.Inverse()` on the rotation of your player, and multiply that by the vector.

```
Vector3 yourVector;
Quaternion inverse = Quaternion.Inverse([player rotation]);
return inverse * yourVector;
```

Multiplying a quaternion by a vector rotates it with the quaternion, so if you invert it it will cancel out the rotation of the player.

Comment: No, I need to get a vector where x - indicates whether the character is moving left or right (from -1 to 1) and y - indicates movement forward, backward (also from -1 to 1), and this vector should take into account the player's rotation.  At the moment, in the character model, only y changes in rotation.  moveDirectionNormalized returns a value that indicates where the movement is directed relative to world space.

Comment: And I need to make a vector that will return directions relative to the player's rotation.  That is, if the character's gaze is directed at the enemy, and the character himself retreats from him, I would like to receive a vector (0, -1).  And if the player's gaze is directed at the enemy and he goes to the right (I remind you that the player is constantly looking towards the enemy, that is, you can walk around the enemy and the character will constantly turn in his direction), then I would like to get a vector (1,0)